# Cannot Decrypt using StandardPBEStringEncryptor

Tags: java, spring-boot, encryption, secret-key, jasypt

I'm trying to decrypt an encrypted key with a password. I'm reading these from my properties file. Decryption fails and the reason is `java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: PBEWithMD5AndDES SecretKeyFactory not available`. Tried with `BasicTextEncryptor` which uses `PBEWithMD5AndDES` as default algo. As I saw the mentioned exception, I tried to use `StandardPBEStringEncryptor`. I have set the algorithm as well but still the face the same issue. Below is the code

```
public class PasswordDecrypt {

    private static char[] password;

static {
    try (InputStream in = PasswordDecrypt.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("application-unitTest.properties");) {
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.load(in);
        password = props.getProperty("jasypt.encryptor.password").toCharArray();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static String decrypt(String text) {
//    BasicTextEncryptor decryptor = new BasicTextEncryptor();
//    decryptor.setPasswordCharArray(password);
//    String decryptedText = decryptor.decrypt(text);
//    return decryptedText;
       StandardPBEStringEncryptor decryptor = new StandardPBEStringEncryptor();
       decryptor.setPasswordCharArray(password);
       decryptor.setAlgorithm("PBEWithMD5AndDES");  String 
       decryptedText = decryptor.decrypt(text);
       return decryptedText;
}
}
```

I'm Unsure how to resolve this. Tried altering the maven dependencies. Following were tried.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.ulisesbocchio</groupId>
    <artifactId>jasypt-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>com.melloware</groupId>
  <artifactId>jasypt</artifactId>
  <version>1.9.4</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jasypt</groupId>
    <artifactId>jasypt</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, most probably you are relying on this algo in one of these custom modules by calling `SecretKeyFactory` object instance there( a module where `StandardPBEStringEncryptor` class is located lacks `jce.jar`, so add it in your module or there).

Also, try adding provider SunJCE to your module code, something like:

```
java.security.Security.addProvider(new com.sun.crypto.provider.SunJCE());
```